# Computing area of raster cells with value "1" in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, area

I have two layers, a raster and a vector. The raster has values 0 and 1. The vector layer has an `"Area"` field for the total area of the shapefile/boundary. I want to compute the area covered of the raster valued with 1 against the vector layer.

Here's an image. What are the steps to achieve this?
The 1's are in white.

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.10 on Windows 10.

Comment: it's the number of white pixels * the area of a pixel

Comment: or: Extract white areas using contour, convert to polygons, dissolve, then calculate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Zonal statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics) with `Statistics to calculate: SUM`
2. Check pixel size under raster layer properties. Mine is 50*50 m
3. Field calculate area field as `sum field * pixel size`:

[image]